# not getting True or False when using boolean in python

Tags: python, boolean

```
 def ping_host(self,host_name):
        """ping host to check if its active"""
        return_responce = os.system('ping -c 1 ' + host_name)
        if return_responce == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: So what do you get? And how are you running this function?

Comment: The script is able to ping host, but it doens't display weather the return_responce is True or False

Comment: use it in a print statement, it will have a boolean return value: `print ping_host(...)`

Comment: Hi Daniel.   This is what I get   
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 1ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.557/0.557/0.557/0.000 ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x=ping_host(self, host_name)
print(x)
```

Comment: Im trying to create a method to use on future scripts.

Comment: @milo ? That doesn't invalidate this answer.

Comment: Understood. I added the print statement to my script. This will work, thank you.   :)

Comment: If my response solved your problem, please mark this answer:) (check mark to the left of post)